# Div control within a php for loop

Tags: php, html, css

Request:
I would like to control the placement of my dynamic divs. Each div should refer to the parent div.

Problem:
The code below does not allow the div positions to be altered based on the parent div. For example, #dldescription top:10%; should use div id="dlitem" as a guide. I tried several tactics but can't seem to make it work as planned.

```
<?php 
include '/scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');

echo '<div id="dlcontainer" style="border-style:groove;">
<div id="dlitem">';

$i= 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
//each style will control the placement of the div relative to the parent div id=dlitem
echo'<style>
    #dldescription_'.$i.'{
        vertical-align:middle;
         position: absolute;
        text-align:center;
        top:10%;
        left:45px;
    }
    #dlimage_'.$i.'{
        vertical-align:middle;
        position: absolute;
        text-align:center;
        top:10%;
        left:45px;
    }
    #dltitle_'.$i.'{
        vertical-align:middle;
         position: absolute;
        text-align:center;
        top:10%;
        left:45px;
    }
    #dllink_'.$i.'{
        vertical-align:middle;
         position: absolute;
        text-align:center;
        top:10%;
        left:45px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>


    <div id="dltitle_'.$i.'" >'.$row['col1'].'</div>
    <div id="dlimage_'.$i.'"  align="center"><img src =./'.$row['col2'].' width="75" height="150"></div>
    <div id="dldescription_'.$i.'"  align="center" ><img src="/img/facebookShare.png">  '.$row['col3'].' off</div>
    <div class="dllink_'.$i.'"  align="center"><a href="http://www.website.com">Limit '.$row['col4'].'</a></div>

';
$i++;

}
echo '</div></div>';



?>
```

Comment: why not just use classes instead of looping through ids ? Like, `.dlimage`, `.dltitle`, `.dllink`, etc. Your actual styles are the same for all of them — so why bother ID-ing them?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position may be helpful

Comment: I want to be able to place each div id in its own spot

Answer (score 0):

To make the div's position relatively to the parent div, you need to change their position from `absolute` to `relative`, like:

```
position:relative;
```

Here's a good guide: http://learnlayout.com/position.html